# FileInputStream with path contains wildcard

Tags: java, wildcard, fileinputstream

I am getting full path for some files from database and then zip those files inside that path. So problem here is the path contains wildcards even for the directory and files too.
Eg:

```
/myfolder/product/test/*.xml
 or
/myfolder/*/*.xml
```

So how can i get those xml files reside under that path to a file input stream to zip them later?

If i dont have wildcards and only the path represent the directory which files resides, i do something like following to add each files. But the problem is my path contains the file names with wildcarts.

```
     //List of the files in the directry
        File f = new File("/folder");
        String files[] = f.list();
        BufferedInputStream in = null;

        for(int i =0;i<files.length;i++){
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/folder/"+files[i]), 1000);
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("somepath/"+files[i]));
        int count;

        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1000)) != -1) {
            out.write(data, 0, count);
        }
       }
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Wildcards are normally interpreted by the shell. You can do something similar in Java using `java.nio.file.FileSystem.getPathMatcher()`. See [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) for more info and usage examples.

Comment: A small note: the java.nio.file package was added in Java 7.

Comment: is there a way to do it with java 6 pls